# execute multiple statements if mysql_query fails

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = sprintf("select * from sometable;");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

modified to:

```
$query = sprintf("select * from sometable;");
$result = mysql_query($query) or $DBError=true;
```

Now I want to execute 2 statements if the query fails, is this possible using the "short above"? e.g. something like this:

```
$query = sprintf("select * from sometable;");
$result = mysql_query($query) or {$DBError=true; $ErrorCode=0;}
```

Comment: Do you want to set result always as `true ` or do you want to set the variables `$DBError` and `$ErrorCode` after the execution of  `mysql_query`? Notice that documentation says that `mysql_query` should **NOT** end with `;` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Just an offtopic tip: mysql library is deprecated and already removed in PHP 7. You should use the mysqli library (i for improved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use conditional statement like:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
 $DBError = true;
 $ErrorCode = 0;
}
```

By the way. mysql_ extension is deprecated. You should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).

Comment: Yes, `mysql` is deprecated, but [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is not. I wouldn't recommend a complete architecture change, as it's unrelated to the OP's question.

Comment: I'm using version 5 but will look into it